# Dynamic load routes file based on Middleware user

Tags: laravel, dynamic, eloquent, routes, laravel-middleware

Im trying to make a dynamic routing based on route file. example if user1 login, `routes/api1.php` will load and if user2 login, `routes/api2.php` will load. is it possible?

sample pseudocode:

```
if user == user1
    then base_path("routes/api1.php") load
if user == user2
    then base_path("routes/api2.php") load
```

inside api1.php will be

```
Route::namespace('UserPath1')->group(function() {
   Route::get('tester', 'ApiIndexController@index');
});
```

inside api2.php will be

```
Route::namespace('UserPath2')->group(function() {
   Route::get('tester', 'ApiIndexController@index');
});
```

Below is currently i do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try and error for hours, its working now. The mistake is where i didnt specify the current auth attribute which is `api_vendor`.

if the current user have token, then the specific route loaded. If no token attach, it will fall into black hole route :D

[image]

The downside of this solution, it cannot be cache using route:cache